# Search using multiple terms in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a JSON response that I would like to filter by either the `emp_name` or `announcement_title`. But no matter what I try, I keep getting back results only when I search by `emp_name`. I would like to know what I would need to do to ensure it works both ways. The JSON response and the method where the search gets invoked are below:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "announcement_title": "title",
            "announcement": "This is an announcement",
            "emp_name": "Somdutta Sengupta",
            "profile_photo": "202209191410925IMG_20220919_135715.jpg",
            "created_at": "2022-08-18 02:47:00"
        },
        {
            "announcement_title": "title of an announcement",
            "announcement": "This is an announcement",
            "emp_name": "Siddhartha Chatterjee",
            "profile_photo": "202210211837932image_cropper_1666357661507.jpg",
            "created_at": "2022-08-18 02:47:00"
        },
        {
            "announcement_title": "This is title of another announcement",
            "announcement": "This is an announcement body",
            "emp_name": "Shaikh Salim Akhter",
            "profile_photo": "202210291143921image_cropper_1667024019467.jpg",
            "created_at": "2022-08-18 02:47:00"
        },
        {
            "announcement_title": "Here is an Announcement",
            "announcement": "This here is a test announcement for the System Team.",
            "emp_name": "Shaikh Salim Akhter",
            "profile_photo": "202210291143921image_cropper_1667024019467.jpg",
            "created_at": "2022-10-18 05:20:12"
        },
        {
            "announcement_title": "Another Test Title",
            "announcement": "Another Announcement for System.",
            "emp_name": "Shaikh Salim Akhter",
            "profile_photo": "202210291143921image_cropper_1667024019467.jpg",
            "created_at": "2022-10-18 05:38:34"
        },
        {
            "announcement_title": "And Another Announcement",
            "announcement": "Another Test Annoucement for the System Team.",
            "emp_name": "Shaikh Salim Akhter",
            "profile_photo": "202210291143921image_cropper_1667024019467.jpg",
            "created_at": "2022-10-18 07:13:57"
        },
        {
            "announcement_title": "Test One",
            "announcement": "Test Announcement",
            "emp_name": "Shaikh Salim Akhter",
            "profile_photo": "202210291143921image_cropper_1667024019467.jpg",
            "created_at": "2022-10-18 07:17:57"
        }
    ]
}
```

The method:

```
  List<dynamic> data = [];
  List<dynamic> query = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    Provider.of<AnnouncementViewModel>(context, listen: false)
        .getAllAnouncements()       //This is where the API gets called
        .then((_) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        data = Provider.of<AnnouncementViewModel>(context, listen: false)
            .announcementFilter;  //We copy the data fetched from API into data   
        query = data;
      });
    });
    initialise();
    super.initState();
  }

  //This is the search method
  searchByQuery(String search) {
    setState(() {
      query = data
          .where((element) =>
              element['emp_name'].toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      query = data
          .where((element) => element['announcement_title']
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(search.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }
```

The code for `AnnouncementViewModel` follows:

```
Map<String, dynamic> _allAnouncements = {};
  List<dynamic> _announcementFilter = [];

  Map<String, dynamic> get allAnouncements {
    return {..._allAnouncements};
  }

  List<dynamic> get announcementFilter {      //This is the getter method that we use in the initState in the above code to retrieve the API data
    return [..._announcementFilter];       
  }

  Future<void> getAllAnouncements() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    _announcementFilter = [];

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(AppUrl.allAnouncements), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${localStorage.getString('token')}'
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _allAnouncements = json.decode(response.body);

      _allAnouncements['data']
          .forEach((value) => _announcementFilter.add(value));
    } else {
      _allAnouncements = {};
    }

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('ALL ANOUNCEMENTS: $_allAnouncements');

      print('ALL FILTERED ANOUNCEMENTS: $_announcementFilter');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: you're overriding ``query`` which is the why it's not working! You could simply check for both the cases as  ``query = data.where((element) => element['emp_name'].toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()) || element['announcement_title'].toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())).toList();``

Answer (score 0):

**update your searchByQuery Function like this:**

```
searchByQuery(String search) {
    setState(() {
      query = data
      .where((element) =>
          element['emp_name'].toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()) 
             || element['announcement_title'].toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
      .toList();
    });
  }
```